# Save run trace in OllyDbg 1.10 using ODbgScript

Tags: windows, automation, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I'm trying to automate Ollydbg 1.10 to run a program in `trace over` mode and save it to a log file.

I'm using [ODbgScript](http://odbgscript.sourceforge.net/) plugin to do this. [Here is the commands manual](http://tuts4you.com/request.php?3431).

The script skeleton looks like this:

```
coe //continue to run after exceptions

opentrace //open run trace window
//save run trace (maybe opentrace isn't necessary)
to //trace over
//exit gracefully...
```

I couldn't find the appropriate way to do this not in the manual nor in google.

Also, is there a way to run a ODbgScript script on OllyDbg 1.10 startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it the dirty way using java's Robot.